# Kotlin "expected no parameters" when attempting to return inline lambda

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, kotlin

I'm trying to write a Kotlin function which returns a lambda taking a parameter. I'm attempting to use code like the following to do this:

```
fun <T> makeFunc() : (T.() -> Unit) {
    return { t: T ->
        print("Foo")
    }
}
```

*Note: In the actual program, the function is more complex and uses `t`.*

Kotlin rejects this as invalid, giving an 'Expected no parameters' error at `t: T`.

However, assigning this lambda to a variable first is not rejected and works fine:

```
fun <T> makeFunc() : (T.() -> Unit) {
    val x = { t: T ->
        print("Foo")
    }

    return x
}
```

These two snippets seem identical, so why is this the case? Are curly braces after a `return` statement interpreted as something other than a lambda?

Additionally, IntelliJ tells me that the variable's value can be inlined, whereas this appears to cause the error.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a curious moment in the design of functional types and lambda expressions in Kotlin.

In fact, the behavior can be described in these two statements:

- Named values of functional types are interchangeable between the ordinary functional type like `(A, B) -> C` and the corresponding type of function with the first parameter turned into receiver `A.(B) -> C`. These types are [assignable from each other](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md).

  So, when you declare a variable that is typed as `(T) -> Unit`, you can pass it or use it where `T.() -> Unit` is expected, and vice versa.
- Lambda expressions, however, cannot be used in such free manner.

  When a function with receiver `T.() -> Unit` is expected, you cannot place a lambda with a parameter of `T` in that position, the lambda should exactly match the signature, a receiver and the first parameter cannot be converted into each other:

  > Shape of a function literal argument or a function expression must exactly match the extension-ness of the corresponding parameter. You can't pass an extension function literal or an extension function expression where a function is expected and vice versa. If you really want to do that, change the shape, assign literal to a variable or use the `as` operator.

  <sup>(from the [document linked above](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md#extension-functions))</sup>

  This rule makes lambdas easier to read: they always match the expected type. For instance, there's no ambiguity between a lambda with receiver and a lambda with implicit `it` that is simply unused.

Compare:

```
fun foo(bar: (A) -> B) = Unit
fun baz(qux: A.() -> B) = Unit

val f: (A) -> B = { TODO() }
val g: A.() -> B = { TODO() }

foo(f) // OK
foo(g) // OK
baz(f) // OK
baz(g) // OK

// But: 

foo { a: A -> println(a); TODO() } // OK
foo { println(this@foo); TODO() } // Error

baz { println(this@baz); TODO() } // OK
baz { a: A -> println(a); TODO() } // Error
```

Basically, it's the IDE diagnostic that is wrong here. Please [report it](http://kotl.in/issue) as a bug to the Kotlin issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a function type `() -> Unit` on receiver `T`, there really isn't a parameter to that function, see `"()"`. The error makes sense. Since you define the function type with `T` as its receiver, you can refer to `T` by `this`:

```
fun <T> makeFunc(): (T.() -> Unit) {
    return {
       print(this)
    }
}
```